# Is the tensor product of two commutative semiprime Q-algebras semiprime?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

A ring is semiprime if it has no non-zero nilpotents. Let $Q$ denote the rational numbers and $A,B$ be a pair of commutative semiprime $Q$ algebras.  Is $A\otimes_Q B$ semiprime? It is well known that the tensor product of two fields in finite characteristic can have nilpotents.

Comment: This is (1) in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9436/reduced-%E2%8A%97-reduced-reduced-what-about-connected , right? (I am still looking for a constructive proof, by the way. The similar-sounding question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/250040/constructive-proof-that-a-kernel-consists-of-nilpotent-elements?rq=1 has been nicely resolved using topos theory. Maybe you can help constructivizing the non-constructive proof from Milne's AG?)

Comment: What you call semiprime is usually called reduced. The positive answer to your question follows directly from [Tag 034N](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/034N) and [Tag 030V](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030V) (3) $\Leftrightarrow$ (5) (since $\mathbb Q$ is perfect).